# Testing react components with PropTypes

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-proptypes

If I have a react component with `PropTypes` defined? what is the best way to test this to ensure that the props are provided without relying on the warnings from the `prop-types` package?

For example if I have a component like this:

```
const Button = ({ text }) => <button>{text ? text : 'default button text'}</button>

Button.propTypes = {
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

I may want to test it to make sure the `default button text` is rendered if I provide no props but in my text I get the default warning:

```
console.error node_modules\fbjs\lib\warning.js:33
    Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `text` is marked as required in `Button`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

Part of my says, the `PropTypes` mean we don't really need to test this. Part of my says we should test for both the warning and the default text as separate test cases.

Any thoughts and opinions on this would be appreciated.

Comment: You should remove the `isRequired` from the prop type and set `Button.defaultProps = {text: 'default button text'}` instead of doing this manually in your `render()` function. Then you can test, if `text` defaults to `default button text` in your test if no text is provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `.isRequired` designation and use `defaultProps` static property to assign default prop values versus doing an ternary conditional. It's an anti-pattern to mark a prop as required and then try and assign it a default value.

Comment: Thank you, I was clearly suffering a mental block here.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide default text then you shouldn't mark `text` property as required. This annotation is for the cases when your component can't work without value that is provided by this prop. This is not this case as we can see.

Answer (score 0):

You could use defaultProps static property. It's a fallback that is set if you don't define a prop.

```js
Button.defaultProps = {
  text: 'default text',
}
```